# Angular @Output emit works only the first time

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular-components

Well... i have this on a child component:

```
this.event.emit(true);
this.calendarProviderService.addEvent(newEvent).subscribe(
    finished => {
        if (finished == true) {
            console.log (finished);
            this.event.emit(false);
        }
    }
)
```

Please check that the "True" emit is working well. On my parent component i have:

```
  <add-event *ngIf="currentActionArea == 'addevent'" (event)="addNewEvent($event)"></add-event>

addNewEvent(event){
    console.log("Emit recibido: " + event);
    if(event == true){
        this.loaderMessage = "Guardando Evento...";
        this.loadingEvents = true;
    } else {
        this.switchButtonModel = '0';
        this.currentActionArea = null;
        this.getEvents();
    }
}
```

But when the subscription is finnished, then the "false" emit it not works.

Can you help me?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Do you see the `console.log (finished)` in the console?

Comment: @AngularFrance yes my friend...

Comment: Hard to say more without a working Plunker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that i use a service to set the emmitter value. This is not a best practice. I solved this using an Subject:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

@Injectable()
export class CalendarProviderService {

/**
 * To emit getActivityWork between two components
 */
private _activityWorkSubject = new Subject<calendarActivityWork>();
public getActivityWork = this._activityWorkSubject.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    /**
     * To set the activity work value
     * @param calendarActivity the activity to show
     */
    doActivityWork(calendarActivity : calendarActivityWork){
        return this._activityWorkSubject.next(calendarActivity);
    }
.
.
.
```

Hope this can help to anybody.